# How can I validate lua struct encoding

Tags: lua

I want to validate whether the encoding that is used in Lua extension **struct** is the same as I want.

I have successfully used "pack" and "unpack" to check whether the input of pack is the same as the output of unpack.

Now, I want to check the output of "pack" to see whether that is expected as well.
Unfortunately, I have not found a way to print that out.

Answer (score 1):

There's the test script from the struct library at http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/teststruct - assuming it's the same one you're using. It has pack and unpack tests.

hth